# Auto Re-connect with database (postgres) using sparkSql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, postgresql-9.3

I am using sparkSql to get data from postgresql but problem occurring whenever database connection lost due to some issues like (database client machine shutdown etc).

**I wanted to make it re-connect automatically, how i can make it  can you suggest me any way using sparkSql only**

Note:- know this features are there in spring boot and hibernate but i am not considering this things

Comment: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:

Comment: Please edit your question and include the entire stacktrace. Thanks.